# Can I select an index in my database by 'index' rather then by 'name' in php mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, database, select

I have this statement in php

```
$rating[0] = $ratings['rating_one'];
```

and as you can see it's selecting column with the name of "rating_one."

Is it possible to select the column using a number instead of a name? i.e.

```
$rating[0] = $ratings[1];
```

Comment: Not directly, but if `$ratings` comes from a database, you can influence the way the array is filled. What code are you using to fetch the data?

Answer (score 0):

No. There's no direct correspondence between a string key and a numeric key. The only oddball exception I can think of are the arrays produced by `mysql_fetch_array`. Its default fetch mode is to create one with both numeric and string keys.

But unless you build the array yourself, there's no way to make `0 = rating_one`

Comment: No need to be sarcastic if your requirements don't match reality.

Comment: I'm not being sarcastic? I appreciate your advise but now you're assumption makes you look ignorant.

Comment: :p = sticking out your tongue.

Comment: :P = Hey that is pretty cool, thanks for the information. It could mean an array of things. I do appreciate your input, as I do every ones. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If the array is produced by [`mysql_fetch_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php), then using `MYSQL_NUM` or `MYSQL_BOTH` will also populate the array integer keys. `MYSQL_BOTH` is the default, so unless you have already checked it might work without you needing to do anything more. **This (or something similar) would be the correct solution to the problem.**

However, as an exercise, it might be possible to "sniff" at what each column's integer number would be because arrays in PHP are ordered containers. So we can do this:

```
$keys = array_flip(array_keys($rating));

// Now you can index using an integer like this:
$itemWithIndex1 = $rating[$keys[1]]; // key 1 == second element
```

I am assuming that `$rating` has *only* string keys; otherwise, the above will never work correctly. And remember: **even if it works, it's the wrong way to do it!**